# Testing the cost of boxing in System.Reactive Observables

Tags: c#, performance, system.reactive

I was curious whether boxing impacts performance in a long chain of `IObservable<T>` operators where `T` is a value type, and whether performance can be improved by changing `T` to `Box<T>` from [`CommunityToolkit.HighPerformance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/high-performance/introduction). I tested this in the form of some unit tests. I also included a test without the long chain of operators to establish how much of the runtime is due to those operators.

The results I got were so surprising that I question whether I'm testing what I think I'm testing. The test where `T` is a bare value type runs fastest. This is the opposite of what I expected. Using `Box<T>` actually hurts performance, with runtime similar to an ordinary reference type. I get similar results when I run all the tests in a batch or run each one cold.

Do my tests actually demonstrate that `T` being a value type is faster, at least for these types?

```
    [TestClass]
    public class PerformanceTests
    {
        private const int RepeatCount = 10000000;
        private const int DoCount = 100;

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestReferenceType()
        {
            Observable.Repeat(new object(), RepeatCount).EmptyDo(DoCount).Subscribe(o => { });
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestValueTypeBaseline()
        {
            Observable.Repeat(0, RepeatCount).Subscribe(o => { });
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestValueType()
        {
            Observable.Repeat(0, RepeatCount).EmptyDo(DoCount).Subscribe(o => { });
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestBoxT()
        {
            Observable.Repeat(Box<int>.GetFrom(0), RepeatCount).EmptyDo(DoCount).Subscribe(o => { });
        }
    }
```

```
    internal static class RxExtensions
    {
        public static IObservable<T> EmptyDo<T>(this IObservable<T> source, int count)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                source = source.Do(o => { });
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
```

Results:

| Test | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `TestValueTypeBaseline` | 1.7s |
| `TestValueType` | 7.2s |
| `TestReferenceType` | 8.8s |
| `TestBoxT` | 8.8s |

Comment: This question really belongs on StackOverflow. Having said that, why do you assume a simple struct type (i.e. int) which is created on the stack would be slower than a reference type on the heap? Also, this should really be benchmarked with BenchmarkDotNet with a memory diagnoser.

Comment: `TestValueTypeBaseline` lacks `EmptyDo(DoCount)` like the others are using. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Hayden It probably wouldn't be accepted on SO because it's "working code." I expected a value type passed through a Rx pipeline to be repeatedly boxed and unboxed. I repeated the experiment with a more complex `struct` type, which runs in ~8s instead of ~7.2s, still consistently ~12% faster than a reference type with the same properties. This seems to contradict Microsoft's advice to avoid using structs as method parameters, and the entire reason for the existence of `Box<T>`.

Comment: @RobH Yes, that's mentioned in the question.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - ah yes, I see it now. Where have you seen the advice about not using structs as method parameters? Also, I'd expect very little boxing in a library like Rx utilising generic types all the way down - what makes you think it will be a significant amount?

Comment: @RobH I never said it would be a significant amount. What's surprising is that it's apparently a *negative* amount relative to reference types. Maybe it has to do with the relative cost of boxing vs. unboxing.